# Confusing Sample Space

Tags: probability

A two letter word without repetition is formed from four letters {a, b, c, d}. Make the Sample Space and define event A that first letter is a.

I know that how to solve this question but, I am confused by 'without repetition'.

There are two meanings

1)  Without repetition of WORD

2)  Without repetition of LETTER

What would be the right option ?  Would we include {aa, bb, cc, dd} in the Sample Space ?

Comment: Since there is only one word at a time, I assume they mean repetition of "letter".  So $aa$ is out, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample space has $4 \times 3 = 12$ ordered outcomes, three of which have `a` first.

```
   ab ac ad
ba    bc bd
ca cb    cd
da db dc
```

If repetition were allowed, then the missing diagonal elements `aa bb cc dd` would be included, for a total of $4 \times 4 = 16$ outcomes.

---

Problems with words like `LETTER`, `STATISTICS`, and `MISSISSIPPI` often
ask for the distinguishable *arrangements* of all the letters. For simpler
examples, there $3!/2! = 3$ distinguishable arrangements of the letters in `MOM`:

```
MMO MOM OMM
```

And there are $4!/(2! \cdot 2!) = 6$ distinguishable arrangement of the letters in `NOON`:

```
NNOO NONO NOON OONN ONON ONNO
```